# Child pages 404 on SPA in AWS S3

Tags: angular, amazon-s3

I have an NG 5 app hosted in AWS S3.  It works fine when I navigate to the root then click though to child pages, but if I navigate direct to a child page I get a 404.  Works fine in Webpack locally so Im thinking this is coz I dont have a real web server?

Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: have you tried using `HashlocationStrategy` ?

Comment: If possible, you need to redirect all requests to `index.html`. Otherwise go with @PardeepJain's solution.

Comment: I have the same problem, but am also using Cloudflare as a CDN on top of the S3 bucket. The accepted answer is not working in this particular case :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to redirect 404 errors to `index.html` in your s3 bucket:
[image: S3 Setting]

Comment: This is what I use for a React single page app, though when I request indexing at search.google.com it shows an error: 'Page cannot be indexed: Not found (404)'.

Do you use any other setting within CloudFront or elsewhere?